# android studio package explorer class showing green backround

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

I have updated my android studio 3.1 recently when i push my code into github and than package explorer showing green background.

[image]

I think thats why my library class cannot access when i make jitpack url and use in another project